# Show that these function are greater-equal zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, inequality

Hi maths people I have question about this. You have functions and you show function is greater-equal to zero. How can you do this?

Example we have function $a(x)$ and other $b(y)$

$a(x) = -x^2+3x-\frac{3}{2}$

$b(y) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (3-y)^2$

Show that $a(x) \geq 0\space\space\space\space$ if $1 \leq x <2$

Show that $b(y) \geq 0\space\space\space\space\space$ if $2 \leq y < 3$

---

How do this good? I think easiest way is draw both function and check when they are all positive in these intervals?

Or this don't count as "show"? How can you do this by calculation?

For $a(x)$ we basically have interval $[1, 2)$, right?

Can I do this?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \left(-x^2+3x-\frac{3}{2}\right)= -1^2+3 \cdot 1 - \frac{3}{2}= \frac{1}{2} > 0$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}\left(-1.9999^2+3 \cdot 1.9999 -\frac{3}{2}\right) \approx \frac{1}{2} > 0$$

This means this function is positive between the interval right? So we have $a(x) \geq 0$

Comment: There is no general way to do it. In this specific way (quadratic function) the way to do it is not too hard, but just calculate the limits at 2 endpoints is not going to work - you need to calculate at **all** points in the interval, which is impossible.

Comment: @user202729 You think they give me no full point in exam when I draw function and say "hey teacher you see on my draw they not negative in these interval!"

Comment: Well, that is not going to work. You need to prove the inequality, for example look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Just because $\lim_{x\to1}a(x)>0$ and $\lim_{x\to2}a(x)>0$, you can't deduce that $f(x)\geqslant0$ in the whole interval. In order to prove it, just observe that$$a(x)=\frac34-\left(x-\frac32\right)^2$$and that$$x\in[1,2)\implies\left|x-\frac32\right|\leqslant\frac12\implies\left(x-\frac32\right)^2\leqslant\frac14.$$
On the other hand, $b(x)$ is a square. Therefore $b(x)^2\geqslant0$ for each real $x$.

Comment: Hey thank you for answered! Why take modulus? Because there is square you take modulus?

Comment: @Hamudii That's called absolute value.

Comment: @user202729 Yes sorry I confuse the words I mean absolute value

Comment: I took the absolute value because that was the way that I found a solution. If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yes very useful thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are probably studying and do exam questions at a not-very-high level, and thus does not have a lot of learned theorem (absolute value or the one mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2535124) answer) (I assume only what had been learned can be used in tests), this is a general method that can apply for all quadratic function:

1. Find the root of the equation. The root of $a(x) = - x^2 + 2x - \frac 3 2$ are $3 \pm \sqrt 3 \over 2$.
2. Factorize the equation. $- x^2 + 2x - \frac 3 2 = (x - {3 - \sqrt 3 \over 2}) ({3 + \sqrt 3 \over 2} - x)$.
3. Because $1 \leq x < 2$, then $x - 1 \geq 0 \Rightarrow x - {3 - \sqrt 3 \over 2} > x - 1 \geq 0$, and $2 - x > 0 \Rightarrow {3 + \sqrt 3 \over 2} - x \geq 0$.
4. Multiply the inequalities above together we have $(x - {3 - \sqrt 3 \over 2}) ({3 + \sqrt 3 \over 2} - x) \geq 0$. Q.E.D.

Alternatively there is a much simpler way for this *particular* inequality:

$$1 \leq x < 2$$
$$ \iff x-1 \geq 0 \text{ and } 2-x>0$$
$$ \Rightarrow (x-1)(2-x) \geq 0 $$
$$ \iff - x^2 + 2x - 2 \geq 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow - x^2 + 2x - 2 + \frac 1 2 \geq 0$$
$$ \iff - x^2 + 2x - \frac 3 2 \geq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Since, $1<\frac{3}{2}<2,$ we obtain 
$$\min_{1\leq x\leq2} a=\min\{a(1),a(2)\}>0.$$

Since $(3-y)^2\geq0$ for all real $y$ we see that $b(y)\geq0.$

Comment: I know why the fact that $1<\frac32<2$ implies what you say it does but I doubt **anybody** asking the question can understand what you are doing here. You should be ashamed of yourself of  instantly posting tons of mediocre answers where you do not in the slightest try to fathom the OP's trouble with their problem, even after the trouble with this attitude has been described to you in details, patiently, several times. Or maybe you are conducting a social experiment to expose the flaws of the rep system on this site? In this case, *mission f... accomplished!*